# Why crontab 1 0 * * * run at 12h (12/24)

Tags: cron

I have a crontab:

```
1 0 * * * /opt/scripts/pg_backup mydb
```

I expected it run at 00:01

But it always run at 12h (12/24), not 0h every day.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What OS/distribution are you using? I'm not clear on what you mean by 12h (12/24), could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: I'm using Centos 7 64bit. 12h (12/24) I mean noonday.

Comment: Is the Centos host that's running crond in the same timezone as you?  Is it possible you're seeing the job run at noon in your local timezone but it's midnight where the server is located?

Comment: I've set timezone of server match with my local timezone.
Here is date in server when I type date command: Sun Jan  3 14:02:05 ICT 2016.
And this is my local time when I type date command: Sun Jan  3 14:02:13 ICT 2016.
The small difference may be caused by switching terminal and type command.